# How to Define Callbacks in Android?

Tags: android, callback

During the most recent Google IO, there was a presentation about implementing restful client applications. Unfortunately, it was only a high level discussion with no source code of the implementation.

In this diagram, on the return path there are various different callbacks to other methods.

[image: google io presentation slide]

**How do I declare what these methods are?**

I understand the idea of a callback - a piece of code that gets called after a certain event has happened, but I don't know how to implement it. The only way I've implemented callbacks so far have been overriding various methods (onActivityResult for example).

I feel like I have a basic understanding of the design pattern, but I keep on getting tripped up on how to handle the return path.

Comment: Exactly what you need. I was looking for the same thing and came across this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

Answer (score 231, accepted):

In many cases, you have an interface and pass along an object that implements it. Dialogs for example have the OnClickListener.

Just as a random example:

```
// The callback interface
interface MyCallback {
    void callbackCall();
}

// The class that takes the callback
class Worker {
   MyCallback callback;

   void onEvent() {
      callback.callbackCall();
   }
}

// Option 1:

class Callback implements MyCallback {
   void callbackCall() {
      // callback code goes here
   }
}

worker.callback = new Callback();

// Option 2:

worker.callback = new MyCallback() {

   void callbackCall() {
      // callback code goes here
   }
};
```

I probably messed up the syntax in option 2. It's early.

Comment: A good example to get a grip on this technique is how a fragment should communicate with another fragment through it's shared Activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: I attempt to "implements" MyCallback interface in a new activity which is not successful and the system requires me to edit the source path on it. So how would i carry out "callBack" from an old activity to a new activity?

Comment: It says that callback variable in the worker class is null for me

Comment: Could someone give the kotlin equivalent?

Comment: The most concise and understandable example one could wish for!

Answer (score 55):

When something happens in my view I fire off an event that my activity is listening for:

**// DECLARED IN (CUSTOM) VIEW**

```
    private OnScoreSavedListener onScoreSavedListener;
    public interface OnScoreSavedListener {
        public void onScoreSaved();
    }
    // ALLOWS YOU TO SET LISTENER && INVOKE THE OVERIDING METHOD 
    // FROM WITHIN ACTIVITY
    public void setOnScoreSavedListener(OnScoreSavedListener listener) {
        onScoreSavedListener = listener;
    }
```

**// DECLARED IN ACTIVITY**

```
    MyCustomView slider = (MyCustomView) view.findViewById(R.id.slider)
    slider.setOnScoreSavedListener(new OnScoreSavedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScoreSaved() {
            Log.v("","EVENT FIRED");
        }
    });
```

If you want to know more about communication (callbacks) between fragments see here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: That #CommunicatingWithActivity tutorial was awesome. Finally understood how to use callbacks after several trials.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Simple and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

No need to define a new interface when you can use an existing one: `android.os.Handler.Callback`. Pass an object of type Callback, and invoke callback's `handleMessage(Message msg)`.

Comment: but how to do it?

Answer (score 29):

Example to implement callback method using interface.

Define the interface, **NewInterface.java**.

package javaapplication1;

```
public interface NewInterface {
    void callback();
}
```

Create a new class, **NewClass.java**. It will call the callback method in main class.

```
package javaapplication1;

public class NewClass {

    private NewInterface mainClass;

    public NewClass(NewInterface mClass){
        mainClass = mClass;
    }

    public void calledFromMain(){
        //Do somthing...

        //call back main
        mainClass.callback();
    }
}
```

The main class, JavaApplication1.java, to implement the interface NewInterface - callback() method. It will create and call NewClass object. Then, the NewClass object will callback it's callback() method in turn.

```
package javaapplication1;
public class JavaApplication1 implements NewInterface{

    NewClass newClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("test...");

        JavaApplication1 myApplication = new JavaApplication1();
        myApplication.doSomething();

    }

    private void doSomething(){
        newClass = new NewClass(this);
        newClass.calledFromMain();
    }

    @Override
    public void callback() {
        System.out.println("callback");
    }

}
```

Comment: till now we were using the interfaces for callback but now square has develop a lib as event-bus Otto .Its really faster and helpful.

Answer (score 22):

to clarify a bit on dragon's answer (since it took me a while to figure out what to do with `Handler.Callback`):

`Handler` can be used to execute callbacks in the current or another thread, by passing it `Message`s. the `Message` holds data to be used from the callback. a `Handler.Callback` can be passed to the constructor of `Handler` in order to avoid extending Handler directly. thus, to execute some code via callback from the current thread:

```
Message message = new Message();
<set data to be passed to callback - eg message.obj, message.arg1 etc - here>

Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        <code to be executed during callback>
    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler(callback);
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

EDIT: just realized there's a better way to get the same result (minus control of exactly when to execute the callback):

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        <code to be executed during callback>
    }
});
```

Comment: Your Runnable post is inside handleMessage method?

Comment: +1 for the best answer. I like the `Callback` version better because you may not necessarily have access to the data needed by `Runnable.run()` at the time that you construct it

Comment: Note: "While the constructor of Message is public, the best way to get one of these is to call Message.obtain() or one of the Handler.obtainMessage() methods, which will pull them from a pool of recycled objects." -- [from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `LocalBroadcast` for this purpose. Here is a quick guide

Create a broadcast receiver:

```
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("speedExceeded"));

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Double currentSpeed = intent.getDoubleExtra("currentSpeed", 20);
        Double currentLatitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        Double currentLongitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);
        //  ... react to local broadcast message
    }
```

This is how you can trigger it

```
Intent intent = new Intent("speedExceeded");
intent.putExtra("currentSpeed", currentSpeed);
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

unRegister receiver in onPause:

```
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

asume the main function is the activity that is triggering the event:

```
fun main() {

val worker = Worker()

worker.setOnCallListener(
    object: OnCallListener {
        override fun onCall() {
            // here we define what should happen
            // when the event accures
            print("event happend")
        }
    }
)

// most events will be called from Android system itself
// but in our case we have to call it manually
worker.listener.onCall()
}
```

the `Worker` class has an instance of Type `OnCallListener` interface
and a method to set its value:

```
class Worker() {
    lateinit var listener: OnCallListener

    fun setOnCallListener(listener: OnCallListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }
}
```

and the `OnCallListener` interface looks like this:

```
interface OnCallListener {
    fun onCall()
}
```