# How to make a function that returns after it is finished playing audio?

Tags: android, synchronous

I want to have a method that plays a specific audio file and only returns when it is finished playing.

Comment: you can implement a callback with interface. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't, it will block a thread and you'll kill CPU for nothing.

Use this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

Here for how to use it:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Comment: As to why I need the function to be blocking: Blocking calls are more readable and more easy to code. In my case, to write the code with async calls would be extremely tiring. I would even sacrifice wasting CPU for it. How can I do it? As an alternative, is it possible to execute the code that makes the blocking calls in a sandbox/just-in-time without wasting processing power? Or is there a tool to convert code with sync calls into async code?

Comment: Learn to code well at first, i know it might be more difficult to put a listener than to make it the trash way but you must make the effort to code well.

Comment: The part of the code that calls the playing function (many times) is to be read and modified by lay people, so I want to keep it readable. So what are my options? Can I make some scripting interface that offers blocking functions?

Comment: Can I make some scripting interface that offers blocking functions? What does that mean?

Comment: I meant to say, is it possible to load parts of the code at runtime from a file/let the user type the code in on the phone (including calling blocking functions), and then execute this user-typed code?

Comment: you mean like making a shell? Like linux one's or windows CMD?