# Android Http API

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am trying to write a Http API in android. I am using a AsyncTask to run the calls to my web service.I am not interested in updating the UI, instead all I want is the data to use in my application logic. This is what I have so far:

```
public class DataManager{
    public static String result;

    public DataManager ()
    {

    }


    public String get ()
    {
        User user = new User ();
        user.execute("http://someuri/service/users/id/21001");
        return user.getResult();
    }
}


public class User extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String>{

    private String result;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet (arg0[0]);

        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute (get);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode () == 200)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResult ()
    {
        return result;
    }

}
```

I want a typical call to be:
     `DataManager manager = new DataManager ();`
    `String value = manager.get ();`

But when I run this I get back null. What is causing this and how can I refactor this code to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of a thread is that it runs concurrently. Basically, here's what you're doing:

```
User user = new User (); // Create User object
user.execute("http://someuri/service/users/id/21001"); // Start thread
return user.getResult(); // Return thread result
```

However, there is no time for the thread to run between "start" and "return result".

I would suggest using some kind of callback; first, make `get()` return `void`, and remove the `return` statement. Then, you pass in some object which implements `YourCallback`, and then call `onCallback(result)` from within `onPostExecute()`.

Your calling code would then look like this:

```
DataManager x = new DataManager();
x.get(new YourCallback() {
    public void onCallback(String result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

There is a much fuller example in [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398416/1438733).