# Send an Exception variable to a function and return the exception details

Tags: android, exception

I am working on android library where I need to pass an exception object to a function. The function should cope with all Exception types and be able to return all of the available data within the exception, such as error message, stacktrace and inner exception.

Below is how I am passing the exception variable to my function within the catch statement.

```
try
{
    txtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTestEdit);
    String test = txtText.getText().toString();
}
catch (NullPointerException ex)
{
    CrashReporter.ReportCrash(ex);
}
```

Below is my function that needs to extract the exception type.

```
public static void ReportCrash(Object exceptionObject)
{
    String exceptionType = exceptionObject.getClass().getName();
    Log.d("Exception Type", exceptionType);     
}
```

In this example the exception type is `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Is there a way I can return the Object called `exceptionObject` to the original exception to extract the stacktrace inner exception and error message.

Please note, this function should cope with all exception types not just a `NullPointerException`

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Sorry for this but to be clear, you want to cast exceptionObject in proper Exception sub Class and deal with each object accordingly?

Comment: My exceptionObject should be returned to the proper exception type. So I can extract the info contained within the exception. That waynthe user can just pass the variable of any exception and the library can handle it without the user having to pass each h bit of information themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is to use a callback, so that each method can handle it properly, but, if there is no callback then have it do some default behavior.

This way you can use properties in the method that had the error.

This question goes into more about callbacks in Android:

[How to Define Callbacks in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

But, basically you create an interface that is implemented in a similar fashion as this:

```
CrashReporter.ReportCrash(ex, new ExceptionCallback() {
    public void myExceptionCallback(Exception e) {
    }
  });
```

This code won't compile, but is just to show a possible way to implement it.

If your class has one callback that is needed, then you can create the callback listener earlier, and just pass it to the `ReportCrash` method.