# Call an activity from non activity class

Tags: android

I want to call an activity from a non activity class and base class send some arguments as bundle. But when I add the following code

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(UserSettingsFragment.this, UserAccount.class);
  /*Sending some arguments*/ 
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("UserName",NAME);
   bundle.putString("Id", ID);
   intent.putExtras(bundle);
   this.startActivity(intent);`
```

eclipse shows the error

```
  The constructor `Intent(UserSettingsFragment, Class<UserAccount>) is undefined.
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: is UserSettingsFragment a fragment class??

Comment: which is non activity & activity class here?

Comment: Is your `UserAccount` activity ? Please show your `UserAccount` class code. Also post your full logcat error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case 1

- I have use other alternative in my case like pass Activity or Context in to constructor and using that context you can call your Next activity.

Case 2

- I think you should use `Interface` and that callback will change your activity as per your response.
- Write Callback method inside `ABC interface` and `implement ABC` in some other Java file which should `extend Activity or Fragment Activity.`
- So that `Override` method will automatically call your event when some particular task will finish at some time.
- I think this is easy and best way to call Intent from `non extend Activity class.`
- See How to manage this with simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

As @Gooziec said:

You need to rewrite you code this way:

```
// If you are calling this for in a Fragment.
final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UserAccount.class);
/*Sending some arguments*/ 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("UserName",NAME);
bundle.putString("Id", ID);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
this.startActivity(intent);`
```

The `Intent` constructor you are using requires a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) as first parameter. Please refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29).

Answer (score 1):

use `getActivity()` instead of `UserSettingsFragment.this`.

I guess you try start another activity from fragment. If so, then you have to pass context of parent's Activity of the fragment to Intent constructor

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer. Given the incomplete question this is the closest assumption that we can make. Fragment class have a getActivity() method that you should replace UserSettingsFragment.this with