# onclick event not working on replaced fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a fragment.
Upon a click on a fragment element an onclick event is fired and causes the activity to replace fragment.

The wierd thing is that the event is fired on the activity class, but that not is the main problem.

On the second activity which I just created i set onclick event on the xml but it doesnt get fired. I also tried to put the same handler on the activity (as it works for the 1st fragment) but it doesnt help.

To sum it up I have 3 layout: activity, 1st fragment which loads as the activity created, and 2nd fragment which gets replace on a click on the 1st fragment.

2 classes: Activity class (1st fragment has no class for it), 2nd fragment class which contains the handler.

I feel like the construction of the application is messed up so dont spare on the tips...

here is the code:

activity:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/chat_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
        />


    public class Chat extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.chat_container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        public void contactClicked(View v){
            Fragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.chat_container, fragment);

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
        }

        public void click(View v){
            Toast.makeText(this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         }
    }
```

1st fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:onClick="contactClicked" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="contactPicture" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="contactName" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

2nd fragment

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/conversation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="koko"
        android:onClick="click" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="MMMMM" />

</LinearLayout>




public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
        }

        public void click(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         }
}
```

thanks for the effort for reading so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you are saying that the below click event which you have defined in the `ConversationFragment` isn't getting executed.

```
public void click(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

If this the case then you have to declare this method inside the parent Activity from where you are replacing fragments. So over and all, `android:onClick` works directly for Activity.

Or If you want to define click listener for views then you have set onClickListener by using `setOnClickListener` in the fragment itself.

Comment: i have a the click(View v) method both on my fragment and my activity. it doesnt fire any of them. furthermore, I just added setOnClickListener to the View(textbox) but it doesnt work as well... :(

Comment: You have to remove `android:onClick="click"` from your TextView!

Comment: after removing the declarative onclick it worked.thanks. why it doesn't work when I declare the method on the xml? is there a way to make it work this way?

Comment: @GZ that's what I mentioned in 1st paragraph that you have to declare onClick event inside the activity from where you are replacing your fragment. There is one more way to handle onClick if you would want to handle click event in fragment itself, which is by implementing *Callback*!

Comment: what do you mean by implementing a callback? can you reffer me to an example?

Comment: Check: [How to Define Callbacks in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

Comment: Cheers and enjoy Android programming :)

Answer (score 0):

change your method name from click to contactClicked

```
public void contactClicked(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```