# How to modify ArrayAdapter' s data from AsyncTask' s postExecute method

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a fragment and in onCreateView I have an adapter and a listview:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item,
            R.id.list_item_textview,
            new ArrayList<String>());

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listeview);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

I also have a separate AsyncTask class and on its onPostExecute method I want to add items to the mAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    if(result !=null){
        mAdapter.clear();
        for(String mString: result){
            mAdapter.add(mString);                
        }
```

I execute the AsyncTask in Fragment's onStart method :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();
    fetchData.execute(location);
}
```

How can I use the Fragment's mAdapter on AsyncTask class to update its data and then notify the listView?

Comment: Is it you AsyncTask class, an inner class of your Fragment class? If yes, you can just use mAdapter. If not, then probably you will need to implement an interface with a callback. Use mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: no it's on a separate class

Comment: @dancer_69,did you see the SO question that i linked to?Also considering this task is specific for a singular API call and that you are quite new to android,you could use the AsyncTask as a nested class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AsyncTask class isn't defined as an inner class, then I suggest you to create an interface with a callback. Let's say for example.

```
public interface Updatable { 
    public void onDataUpdate(List<String> data);
}
```

Later, you have to implement that interface in your fragment, and create a setUpdatableListener method in your AsyncTask class. So in a way that, you first create your AsyncTask instance, then you call the setUpdatableListener passing the listener, then you call execute.Later on On the postExecute method you have to do this:

```
mListener.onDataUpdate(result);
```

Of course, later your listener in the fragment will be on charged of updating the mAdapter data, and the ListView.

Please check this question:

[How to Define Callbacks in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

for a quick simple explanation on how to use interface and callbacks.

Comment: I haven't use interfaces at all, and I don't understand how to connect it with my code. Can you please give a more detailed example with the code I provided? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

based on the API:

[ArrayAdapter.addAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) will add all the data that you have obtained in the async task
[ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) will infor the array adapter that the data has changed
You could also set [ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(boolean notifyOnChange)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange%28boolean%29) to true so that the adapter is notified of the change.

and incase you want to modify your dataset more explicitly,you could look into

- [add(T object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29)
- [addAll(Collection collection)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#%20addAll%20%28Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%20collection%29)
- [addAll(T... items)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%20%28T...%20items%29)

Maybe if you want to empty your dataset before adding the new data there also is:
 -[clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29)

Do not forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after every change you make to your data.
to conclude this code should achieve whatever you are trying.

```
arrayAdapter.addAll(data);
arrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

PS:I picked all this from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

**EDIT**:since you mentioned modify,this is for completeness sake:

You can also modify individual items using [ArrayAdapter.getItem (int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) ,modify the data and call notifyDataSetChanged(),

or else if you want to replace an item,[ArrayAdapter.remove(T)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) to remove the object and reinsert using [ArrayAdapter.insert (T object, int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29)

There you go,that completes CRUD!

**EDIT2**:Since you mentioned separate class,you could use an async listener like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ListView listView` a member of the class and use `listView.setAdapter(mAdapter)` on your `onPostExecute` method.

Your ListView automatically refresh data when you bind a new adapter.

Comment: How do you even get the adapter if asynctask is a different non-inner class?

Comment: You pass the adapter as a parameter when you create the asynctask