# How to check the response of a service when android SDK initializes?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-library

I'm making an Android library which can be used in different projects. Before opening the required posts, at the time of sdk initialization I have to check the response by hitting service that it is true or not? How can I do that? Please tell. Variables will be passed by the sdk user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Define Callbacks in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)