# can't resolve finish methods --call from Android Studio methods

Tags: java, android, methods, resolve

Android Studio 3.0.1

It works in QAnswerQuestion.java code

```
List<Integer> wrongList = UIResponse.checkAnswer(list);
if (wrongList.size() == 0)
{
  new AlertDialog.Builder(QAnswerQuestion.this).setTitle("Info")
       .setMessage("You are awesome and all answers are correct!")
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           finish();
         }
         }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
}
```

but when I try to put the above code in UIResponse.java

and call in QAnswerQuestion.java like this:

```
UIResponse.lastQuestionDialog(QAnswerQuestion.this,list);
```

and UIResponse.java code is

```
static void lastQuestionDialog(final Context context, List<Question> list)
{
  List<Integer> wrongList = UIResponse.checkAnswer(list);
  if (wrongList.size() == 0)
  {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Info")
          .setMessage("You are awesome and all answers are correct!")
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
               {
                 finish();
               }
              }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }
}
```

It says "can't resolve finish methods "

Comment: add `this.finish();` see if it works?

Comment: If you are using `Fragments` call `getActivity().finish();`

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi `this.finish()` is not going to work because its inside anonymous class .

Comment: How about `getApplicationContext().finish()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are showing dialog in other class which is `UIResponse` . And `finish()` is method of `Activity`.one simple solution can be .

```
static void lastQuestionDialog(final Context context, List<Question> list)
 {
  List<Integer> wrongList = UIResponse.checkAnswer(list);
   if (wrongList.size() == 0)
   {
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Info")
      .setMessage("You are awesome and all answers are correct!")
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
           {
             ((Activity)context).finish();
           }
          }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
    }
 }
```

Other then this I suggest you to use an callback interface to notify `Activity` about the dialog actions so that you can manage them in your `Activity` . Read [how-to-define-callbacks-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android).