# How to update textview in activity from fragment's recyclerview ViewHolder class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem in updating `textview` in activity class whenever `recyclerview` item is deleted from it. `getActivity()` is not available here. Thanx in advance guys.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView delete_from_cart;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        delete_from_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // here I want to change the textview
                DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                dh.deleteCartDetail(product_name.getText().toString());
                delete(getLayoutPosition());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try interface/broadcastreceiver/eventbus for click callback to activity

Comment: getLayoutPostion() >>> getAdapterPosition()

Comment: pass `context` referent with adapter constructor.

Comment: @KhaledLela not working with context.

Comment: Check my answer that show how to update activity using callback mentioned by @Khermraj answer.

Comment: @KhaledLela Thnx buddy. You make it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    public interface MyCallback{
        public void updateText(String text);
    }

    final private MyCallback callback;
    public MyAdapter(MyCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }


  ... Some Other code
  delete_from_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do other stuff
            callback.updateText("some text");
        }
    });
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback{

    @Override
    public void updateText(String someText){
        myTextView.setText(someText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be different ways to implement this. Below are some.

1. Use **[interface callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3398363/6891563)**, which will be passed in constructor of that Adapter class. (**Best for your requirement.**)
2. Pass **activity reference** in `Adapter` class, and call activity method to update textview. Like `activity.updateText()`;
3. You can use **[EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)**. That can communicate in all over your app.